# Store return value of a compiled exe into a batch variable

Tags: batch-file, return-value

I've read topics here and on the internet about the argument but the solutions offered do not work for me.
Firstly I'll tell you what I want to do:
I have a compiled c file (.exe) that returns various integers depending on the situation.
I want to store said return value in a variable in batch. From what I've read, there's no specific command to do this (like 'v=$?` in shell that assigns to the variable the last returned value), but I found instead a workaround that uses the for loop.
The code I found is the following:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('test.exe') do SET OUTPUT=%%a
echo %OUTPUT%
```

But when I run the batch file, I get `ECHO is off`.
I'm a complete beginner in batch, I simply searched "store return value in batch" and the code above is what got spit out. Any insight or help on the problem is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Weird; that should work now that you've fixed the typo. The only other thing I can think is that your exe is one of those weird ones that displays everything in STDERR for some reason. See if `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('test.exe 2^>^&1') do SET OUTPUT=%%a` sets the variable correctly for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer given by Mofi**

> Dillon Wreek wants the exit code (also called exit value, return
> value, return code or in CMD syntax errorlevel) of test.exe and not
> the output of the text.exe written to handle stdout. So all needed by
> Dillon Wreek is a batch file with first line @echo off, second line
> test.txt, third line echo %errorlevel% resulting in writing into
> console window the value 1 or 2 or 3 or ... 12 and fourth line pause
> to see the output on double clicking on batch file.

Basically:

```
test.exe
set var=%errorlevel%
echo %var%
```